# How to manage app logo because some device display different app logo

Tags: android, android-studio

In my android device app logo shows in rounded view and also view square whitespace around with app logo.
Please help me what should I do for the same.

Comment: Are you talking about https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive?

Comment: Check also https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio